Why is tkinter making 2 extra windows?
I'm making a game in tkinter using classes to switch frames, however whenever I run it I get 2 extra windows one of which when destroyed gives this error:
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Thonny\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1921, in call return self.func(*args) File "D:\Thonny\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 2342, in destroy Misc.destroy(self) File "D:\Thonny\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 665, in destroy self.tk.deletecommand(name) _tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command

I think it may be due to calling Tk() and also something to do with super() and init but i dont really know what they do
My code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk,font
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import messagebox
import shelve
from PIL import ImageTk,Image     #I know there are some that are probably unnescesary but
                                  #it works so i dont waant to touch it T.T

Game=Tk()

class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        global background
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('992x558')
        background=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('background.png'),master=self)
        backgroundlabel= Label(self,image=background).place(x=0,y=0)
        self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self._frame = None
        self.switchframe(npcheck)

    def switchframe(self, frameclass):
        newframe = frameclass(self)
        print(frameclass(self))
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()            # destroy old frame
        self._frame = newframe             #set new frmae
        self._frame.grid()              ##draw new frame

class npcheck(tk.Frame):                #new player check
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #tk.Frame.__init__(self, master,image=background)
        backgroundlabel= Label(self,image=background).place(x=0,y=0)
        q=Label(self, text= 'New or existing player?')
        q.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=50,pady=50)
        gobutton= Button(self,text='New Player.', command=lambda: master.switchframe(accountcreation))
        gobutton.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W,padx=50,pady=50)
        gobutton= Button(self,text='Existing Account.', command=lambda: master.switchframe(login))
        gobutton.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=E,padx=50,pady=50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.mainloop()  

I tried removing the Game=Tk() and fiddling with it a bit however this only broke it more T.T

there should only be one Tk in your code, i see 3 of them, which is why you have 3 windows, remove the 2 that are not needed, only leave the one inside Game(tk.Tk):

What is the point of assigning Game=Tk(), when you immediately replace it by creating a class that is also named Game?  You can only have one thing named Game...

Once question per post. Create new post please. Read [ask] and [answer]

You're getting extra windows because you're inadvertently instantiating Tk multiple times (in a few places throughout the code). Note that I've commented out or otherwise disabled the background image stuff, since I don't have those files on hand.
I've added some notes (as comments) regarding convention / style, but this should work as written.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
# you're already importing something from messagebox above; if you need other
# methods from that module, just add them there
# from tkinter import messagebox
import shelve
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
# from tkinter import *  # it's best to avoid star imports. Instead, just access
# tk widgets like this: tk.Label, tk.Button, etc.

# Game=Tk()  # this is creating a window, but your Game class already
# inherits from tk.Tk, so you don't need to instantiate it here


class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
         # tk.Tk.__init__(self)  # you don't need this *and* super(), just use one - also, using both is creating yet another window!
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('992x558')
        # background=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('background.png'),master=self)
        backgroundlabel=tk.Label(self,image=None).place(x=0,y=0)
        # self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self._frame = None
        self.switchframe(npcheck)

    def switchframe(self, frameclass):
        newframe = frameclass(self)
        print(frameclass(self))
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()            # destroy old frame
        self._frame = newframe             #set new frmae
        self._frame.grid()              ##draw new frame


class npcheck(tk.Frame):  # this should be capitalized, e.g. NpcCheck              #new player check
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  # you can use super() here too!
        # super().__init__(master)  # like this
        #tk.Frame.__init__(self, master,image=background)
        backgroundlabel= tk.Label(self,image=None).place(x=0,y=0)
        q=tk.Label(self, text= 'New or existing player?')
        q.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ew',padx=50,pady=50)
        gobutton= tk.Button(self,text='New Player.', command=lambda: master.switchframe(accountcreation))
        gobutton.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='w',padx=50,pady=50)
        gobutton= tk.Button(self,text='Existing Account.', command=lambda: master.switchframe(login))
        gobutton.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='e',padx=50,pady=50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.mainloop()

I'd recommend taking a sec to look over the PEP8 style guide, and reading up on what super() does!

What do you suggest for the tkinter variable declaration? (refer to question edit)

Inheriting from tk.Tk  in your main app class is all you need! The call to super().__init__() is what's initializing tkinter (that's what super is - the "superclass" of whatever class is inheriting from it!)
